# How can I change polymer date picker calendar header & selected date background color?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

**How can I change polymer date picker calendar header & selected date background color?**
I used this polymer element: https://github.com/Collaborne/paper-date-picker-item

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to your question:

```
paper-date-picker {
  --default-primary-color: red;
}
```

Comment: @engr.jalal are you using `paper-date-picker` element?

Comment: I used paper-date-picker-item element. source: https://github.com/Collaborne/paper-date-picker-item